# Always get "You don't have the user rights to view this page" on docker compose using nginx + php-fpm

Tags: php, docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose

I've been struggling with this one for the last day.

I'm trying to setup a simple dev environment. I started by creating a self signed certificate

I used this command on wsl:
`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes  -keyout server.key -out server.crt`
on the Common Name question I've answered: `test.lan`

My docker compose is as follows:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/test.lan.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/test.lan.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - ./../app:/var/www/test.lan
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
  php-fpm:
    image: php:fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./../app:/var/www/test.lan
```

my nginx config file is

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt; # dummy cert
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key; # dummy cert

        root /var/www/test.lan;
        index index.html index.php;

        # Make site accessible
        server_name test.lan;


        location / {
                # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
                try_files $uri $uri/ @rewriteapp;
        }

        location @rewriteapp {
                # rewrite all to index.php
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
        }

        location ~\.php {
                try_files $uri /index.php;
                fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

}
```

Certificates are being synchronized to the nginx/certs folder
Nginx config file is being loaded
I've added on windows hosts `127.0.0.1 test.lan`

If I to `http://test.lan` everything works well , if I visit `https://test.lan` I get the *message*:

> Access to test.lan was denied
> You don't have the user rights to view
> this page.
> HTTP ERROR 403